# Google spreadsheet : How to calculate average considering a month

Tags: google-sheets, average

I tried many ways (without success) to edit a function in order to calculate an average, for a month :

Column A :

```
05/05/2014
05/12/2014
05/17/2014
06/05/2014
06/12/2014
06/17/2014
```

Column B :

```
17
18
13
15
19
11
```

I would like to calculate the average but only for the month of May
and for the month of June

So I began to write :

```
=AVERAGEIF(A:A; .... ; B:B)
```

I don't know what to write in place of the dots to symbolize the month

Many thanks for your help

Regards

Comment: Can you add a column with the month (e.g. C1 -> =MONTH(A1), etc)?  Then you could use `AVERAGEIF` with criteria "=5".

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
=AVERAGE(FILTER(<DATERANGES>, MONTH(<DATERANGES>) = <MONTH_NUMBER>))
```

No `<>`. Those are just to indicate the values you should fill in. So assuming your dates are in Column A and you want the averages for the month of May, it would look something like:

```
=AVERAGE(FILTER(A1:A, MONTH(A1:A) = 5))
```

**EDIT**: I think I may have misunderstood, if you want to get averages of Column B based off Months in Column A, then you can change the range you filter.

```
=AVERAGE(FILTER(B1:B, MONTH(A1:A) = 5))
```

Comment: Thanks! The last edited solution helped me escape the trap of countifs / sumifs / averageifs size mismatch error!